# counting items from a multi level category tree that belong to a certain upper level tree in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, tree, categories

So suppose I have a table named categories...it contains...well...categories

table categories contain fields 'id', 'name' and 'parentID'

```
Table Categories:
id    name     parentID
1    cat1      null
2    cat2      null
3    cat3      null
```

Further it also contains subcategories that are children categories of the categories above. So:

Table Categories:

```
id    name     parentID
1    cat1      null
2    cat2      null
3    cat3      null
4    cat4      1
5    cat5      1
6    cat6      2
7    cat7      2
8    cat8      3
9    cat9      3
```

And suppose we have items that belongs to categories.....so we have the table item:

```
id name catID
1  boo   9
2  kya   8
3  muwa  6
4  haha  7
```

and I want to count the number of items that belongs to a certain category including its subcategories. So if I wanna count items that belong to cat3, it should return 2 items since boo and kyaa belong to category 9 and 8 which in turn are subcategories of cat3...

what mysql query would you recommend me execute to go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Note by @jakoch: The previous link is not valid anymore.
For an alternate description, see:
http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: The article explains how to retrieve categories trees, but how can you apply that to the OP's question?

Comment: I was hoping for an actual example that demonstrates how to find the number of "items" that belong to a category and its subcategories.